# Hopf Fibration Question

Tags: algebraic-topology, hopf-fibration

Suppose I have a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4-$ {$0$}.

Since $\mathbb{R}^4-$ {$0$} $\cong S^3$ can I map the vectors of $\phi$ in $\mathbb{R}^4-$ {$0$} to $\mathbb{R}^3-$ {$0$} by the Hopf fibration since $\mathbb{R}^3-$ {$0$} $\cong S^2$ ?

Comment: Given any map $f : \mathbb{R}^4 - \{0\} \to S^3$, and the Hopf fibration $h : S^3 \to S^2$, you can of course form the composition $h\circ f\circ\phi : \mathbb{R} \to S^2$ and $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\}$. Do you want this composite to have certain properties?

Comment: I just needed clarification. I got some mixed answers from talking to some people but I am looking to keep length invariant.

Comment: You should edit your question to include more details about what it is exactly you're trying to establish. Also include what the mixed answers are, then maybe someone can clarify.